# page.screen got white backgroud in a part of image

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to screenshot this site: ttps://templates.swipepages.com/fitness-standard
In chromin it show well, but in image result it will have a white space. Is this from CSS of site or chromin browser?
[image result error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbDAv.png)
[The page show well on chromin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4nz6.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question now and add a minimal script showing how you get this scrrenshot.

Comment: Thank you for reply, i fixed it, it's problem about site got screenshot. API screenshot of browser will zoom out very large then width of header site is very large then make site header heigh it too high ...

Comment: Glad that you fixed it! If it was a specific error or a typing mistake it is better to delete your question, since there will not be no answer to it. Cheers!